# RoundingMode.DOWN for BigDecimal rounding up instead

Tags: java, rounding, bigdecimal

I am trying to write a program that calculates the square root of an integer (n) with a specified precision (k) provided by user using the newton's method. The program is working fine however I am noticing what I think is a rounding issue. Can someone help me solve this?

**For example:**

- for input:  n = 81  and k = 7     / for input: n = 87026  and k = 11
- program is printing:  9.0000001   / program is printing: 295.00169491039
- what I want to print: 9.0000000   / what I want to print: 295.00169491038

Here is my code:

```
Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
//print instructions and scan user input
System.out.println("~ This program computes the square root of an integer ~");
System.out.print("\n" + "Enter a non-negative integer [not greater than 1 billion (10^9)] n: ");
int n = userInput.nextInt();
System.out.print("\n" + "Enter a non-negative integer [not greater than 10 thousand (10^4)] k: ");
int k = userInput.nextInt();
userInput.close();
// declaring and converting variables
int p = (k + 1);
BigDecimal num = new BigDecimal(n);
BigDecimal guess = new BigDecimal(n);
BigDecimal newGuess;
BigDecimal sqrt;
// calculating error using int p
BigDecimal error = BigDecimal.ONE.movePointRight(-p);
// calculating guess using int p
BigDecimal diff = BigDecimal.ONE.scaleByPowerOfTen(p);
// newton's loop 
while (diff.compareTo(error) == 1) {
    newGuess = guess.subtract(
        ((guess.multiply(guess)).subtract(num))
        .divide(guess.add(guess), k, RoundingMode.DOWN));
    diff = newGuess.subtract(guess);
    if (diff.signum() == -1) {
        diff = diff.abs();
    }
    guess = newGuess;
}
// printing sqrt to screen    
sqrt = guess;
System.out.println("loop calculated: " + "\n" + sqrt);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the loop, a sum is calculated iteratively according to the Newton's method, whereby *each* summand is rounded and *contributes* to the error. To illustrate this, it is useful to additionally output the initial value for `guess` and all values for `diff`.  For the example `n = 81, k = 7` the output is:

```
guess: 81
diff: 40.0000000
diff: 19.5121951
diff: 8.8591124
diff: 3.1073634
diff: 0.5070567
diff: 0.0142611
diff: 0.0000112
diff: 0E-7
loop calculated: 
9.0000001
```

If all `diff`-values are subtracted from `guess`, the *exact* value is `9.0000001`, i.e. the individual rounding errors have resulted in a deviation of `0.0000001`. To change this behavior, the scale can be increased e.g. by one, `k += 1`, *before* the loop, and reset to the actual value with `guess = guess.setScale(k - 1, RoundingMode.DOWN);` *after* the loop. Then the output is:

```
guess: 81
diff: 40.00000000
diff: 19.51219512
diff: 8.85911242
diff: 3.10736339
diff: 0.50705669
diff: 0.01426108
diff: 0.00001129
diff: 0E-8
loop calculated: 
9.0000000
```

Now the result matches the expectation. The change can be verified using the second example `n = 87026 , k = 11`, for which the output is without the change:

```
guess: 87026
diff: 43512.50000000000
diff: 21755.75001149068
diff: 10876.87510915519
diff: 5436.43840462864
diff: 2714.22604199009
diff: 1349.16761702433
diff: 659.01405739182
diff: 300.74946658011
diff: 107.35187252479
diff: 18.35523727653
diff: 0.56993647588
diff: 0.00055055104
diff: 5.1E-10
diff: 0E-11
loop calculated: 
295.00169491039
```

with an analog error in the result. With the modification the output is:

```
guess: 87026
diff: 43512.500000000000
diff: 21755.750011490686
diff: 10876.875109155187
diff: 5436.438404628644
diff: 2714.226041990089
diff: 1349.167617024336
diff: 659.014057391816
diff: 300.749466580112
diff: 107.351872524786
diff: 18.355237276533
diff: 0.569936475871
diff: 0.000550551041
diff: 5.13E-10
diff: 0E-12
loop calculated: 
295.00169491038
```

in accordance with the expected value.